# Firefox canvas with radial gradient and globalAlpha=0.1 not working on two machines

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas

I've encountered this issue right now with Firefox 70.0.1 64bit on 2 customer's machines:

Windows 10, version 1809 build 17763.805, graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
Windows 10, version 1903 build 18362.356, graphics Intel UHD Graphics 620

On customer's machines both circles has same bright green color:

[Here is broken version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35I2c.jpg)

On all my machines (linux, ff 70 64bit) and in Chromium/Chrome I see left circle dark green, right circle very faint green (opacity 0.1). It also works fine on every single virtual.

[Here is working version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIE82.jpg)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = '#777777';
context.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 10);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
context.globalAlpha = 0.30000001192092896;
var grd = context.createRadialGradient(150, 100, 99, 150, 100, 100);
grd.addColorStop(0, "green");
grd.addColorStop(1, "transparent");
context.fillStyle = grd;
context.lineWidth = 0;
context.strokeStyle = '';
context.beginPath();
context.arc(150, 100, 50, 0, 6.283185307179586);
context.fill();
context.globalAlpha = 1;
context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
context.fillStyle = '#777777';
context.fillRect(250, 100, 100, 10);
context.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
context.globalAlpha = 0.10000001192092896;
var grd = context.createRadialGradient(300, 100, 95, 300, 100, 150);
grd.addColorStop(0, "green");
grd.addColorStop(1, "transparent");
context.fillStyle = grd;
context.lineWidth = 0;
context.strokeStyle = '';
context.beginPath();
context.arc(300, 100, 50, 0, 6.283185307179586);
context.fill();
context.globalAlpha = 1;
context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500 style="background-color: black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: I'm using the same Firefox 70.0.1, 64-bit on Windows 10, v1903, build 18362.356 and GTX 970 and it looks like the working version for me. Note that, if this is because of a hardware or driver issue, it's unlikely you'll be able to fix it from the browser.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/